# Management app server is missing from port 8002

Tags: marklogic

In MarkLogic version 5, the management app server that is supposed to be on port 8002 is missing. Will it be created automatically while upgrading it to MarkLogic version 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the [Prerequisites for Application Services Portion of the Upgrade](https://docs.marklogic.com/5.0/guide/installation/intro#id_98861) for in the MarkLogic 5 install guide. For [MarkLogic 7 the prerequisites look similar](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/intro#id_98861). So I would say that if ML5 didn't install that app server, ML7 won't either. But the upgrade logic is moderately complex and the answer might depend on configuration details.

If you want to debug the MarkLogic 5 upgrade, check the appropriate `ErrorLog.txt` from the time of the upgrade:

```
If the conditions are not met, then the upgrade logs an error to the ErrorLog.txt file
```

The section of the docs linked above also outlines the correct configuration for the new app servers. So you can set them up yourself, and resolve any conflicts that way.

```
Port    8002
Name    Manage
Root    Apps/
Error Handler   manage/error-handler.xqy
URL Rewriter    manage/rewriter.xqy
Database    App-Services
Privilege   manage
```